# Linking object files fails symbol not found

Tags: assembly, ld

I am using nasm assembler and then linking with ld and it has worked up until today when I get this error

```
$ ld -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o objctest.o -lSystem
ld: warning: -arch not specified
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     -u command line option
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64
```

Assembly Code

```
global  _main

align 4, db 0x90

section .text
_main:
push ebp
mov  ebp, esp
mov eax, 88
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret
```

Comment: Which parameter on your `ld` command line refers to your assembly code?

Comment: objctest.o which I generated with nasm -fmacho objctest.s

Comment: Doesn't the `-o` option for `ld` mean that the given file is an output object? Check `man ld`. I would leave off the `-o` or it will attempt to overwrite your `objctest.o`.

Comment: ld -macosx_version_min 10.8.0 -o objctest objctest.o -lSystem